# How do I optimize the speed of my Sage reducibility algorithm?

Tags: sage

Suppose I have the polynomial `f(x) = x^n + x + a`. I set a value for `n`, and want `0 <= a <= A`, where `A` is some other value I set. This means I will have a total of `A` different polynomials, since `a` can be any value between `0` and `A`.

Using Sage, I'm finding the number of these A polynomials that are reducible. For example, suppose I set `n=5` and `A=10^7`. That would tell me how many of these `10^7` polynomials of degree 5 are reducible. I've done this using a loop, which works for low values of `A`. But for the large values I need (ie. `A=10^7`), it's taking an extremely long & impractical amount of time. The code is below. Could someone please help me meaningfully optimize this?

```
x = polygen(QQ)
n = 5
A = 10^7
count = 0

for i in range(A):
    p_pol = x^n + x + i

    if not p_pol.is_irreducible():
        count = count + 1
        print(i)



print('Count:' + str(count))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small, but in this case pretty meaningless optimization is to replace `range(A)` with `xrange(A)`.  The former will create an array of all integers from `0` to `A - 1` which is a waste of time and space.  `xrange(A)` will just produce integers one by one and discard them when you're done.  Sage 9.0 will be base on Python 3 by default where `range` is equivalent to `xrange`.

Let's do a little experiment though.  Another small optimization will be to pre-define the part of your polynomial that's constant in each loop:

```
x = polygen(QQ)
n = 5
A = 10^7
base = x^n + x
```

Now just as a general test, let's see how long it takes in a few cases to add an integer to the polynomial and then compute its irreducibility:

```
sage: (base + 1).is_irreducible()
False
sage: %timeit (base + 1).is_irreducible()
1000 loops, best of 3: 744 µs per loop
sage: (base + 3).is_irreducible()
True
sage: %timeit (base + 3).is_irreducible()
1000 loops, best of 3: 387 µs per loop
```

So it seems in cases where it is irreducible (which will be the majority) it's a little faster, so let's say on average it will take 387µs per.  Then:

```
sage: 0.000387 * 10^7 / 60
64.5000000000000
```

So this will still take a little over an hour, on average (on my machine).

One thing you can do to speed things up is parallelize it, if you have many CPU cores.  For example:

```
x = polygen(QQ)
A = 10^7
def is_irreducible(i, base=(x^5 + x)):
    return (base + i).is_irreducible()

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool()
A - sum(pool.map(is_irreducible, xrange(A)))
```

That will in principle give you the same result.  Though the speed up you'll get will only be on the order of the number of CPUs you have at best (typically a little less).  Sage also comes with some [parallelization helpers](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/parallel/sage/parallel/decorate.html) but I tend to find them a bit lacking for the case of speeding up small calculations over a large range of values (they *can* be used for this but it requires some care, such as manually batching your inputs; I'm not crazy about it...)

Beyond that, you may need to use some mathematical intuition to try to reduce the problem space.